# How to add TSLint rules to Sonarqube Typescript plugin?

Tags: typescript, sonarqube, metrics

An existing TS project with a set of TSLint rules activated want to be analyzed with Sonarqube, therefore I installed the latest LTE version of sonarqube as well as TS plugin provided by Sonar.

Despite the fact the TS plugin includes a good set of rules, the ones currently used by the project does not match one-to-one with TSPlugin rules.

I want to import the rules used and defined in the project in Sonarqube, How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is impossible to add TSLint rules to SonarTS SonarQube plugin.